# Bash script treating a multiple arguments like a single argument. Need multiple arguments as multiple arguments

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, bash-scripting

Like "sudo" I would like to create a command that lets me test if the web page can do things like ping, wget, cat, etc. This bash script works OK for single commands like 'www ./test.py' but the cat command need other information.
If "www ping 192.168.X.X" is entered this is returned. (.X.X is some local ip)

sudo: ping 192.168.X.X: command not found

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$@" ]
   then
     echo "No arguments supplied"
     sudo -u www-data bash
     exit 0
else
     echo "Hello world"
     sudo -u www-data "$*"
     exit 1
fi

#sudo -u www-data bash
```

PS. This could be used for any user on the system. I just used www-data as an example.

Comment: Are you using `"$*"` where you want `"$@"` and vice versa?

Comment: `[ -z "$*" ]` can't tell the difference between no arguments and one argument that is an empty string.

Comment: Kamil M thanks this is my first post and I would like to up-vote your answer.  It worked thanks

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824590/propagate-all-arguments-in-a-bash-shell-script) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811345/how-to-pass-all-arguments-passed-to-my-bash-script-to-a-function-of-mine) on stackoverflow.